# What is this slimy, orange shiny substance on my brick floor?

Tags: floor, brick

We just bought an old house (built late ‘70s), and noticed this substance all over the indoor brick floors. What is it?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is slimy to the touch? Is there a smell? My first thought was gold fingernail polish based on the look.

Comment: Where in the world is this house located? Was there any sort of pre-sale inspection done? Can you contact the previous owners (maybe through the bank/mortgage company/realtor) to ask them about it? Is it actually wet/slimy or is it dry now?

Comment: This looks like the entire floor was sealed at one time. You see traces of the finish on the brick but the joints are still intact. The orange coloring is underneath whatever was used as the sealant. This could be efflorescence from the mortar. Regardless, the joints will need to be cleaned by removing the sealant.

Comment: Do you know if they tried to quickly seal the bricks to 'tidy' the floor up for the sale? If so it could just be the excess sealant settled into the lower joints.